# An unknown error has occurred Facebook Page feed only very recently

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am getting error message

> {
>      "error": {
>         "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
>         "type": "OAuthException",
>         "code": 1,
>         "fbtrace_id": ""
>      }

while fetching page feed using facebook page feed using curl.
It working fine till recently. Does any one if there is any changes or how to figure it out.

I do believe that the facebook has made changes to access token. Is this right.

Code that I send to curl is as below after getting accessing token and its response is show below

> Message: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/{Page ID}/feed?fields=id,story,permalink_url,from,name,message,picture,created_time,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true).limit(50),shares&until=1491434308&since=1490829508&{"access_token":"{Token ID} |{TOKEN ID PART}","token_type":"bearer"}): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Any help??  Is there any app permission to fetch pages feed. and to get the access token. Thanks in advance

Comment: _“I do believe that the facebook has made changes to access token. Is this right.”_ - it has changed with API v2.3, yes - and v2.2 was shut down end of March. This has been discussed frequently already, and is also mentioned in the official change log.